# iOS : is iOS monitor XMLHttpRequest opened in a webview?

Tags: ios, xmlhttprequest, nsurlrequest, nsmutableurlrequest

Is iOS monitor an `XMLHttpRequest` opened in a webview ?

I would like to keep this opened connection when my app enter in suspended background, and now it is not the case. `iOS` kill my connection.

I have tried to setNetworkServiceType to `NSURLNetworkServiceTypeVoIP` with no results.

```
[myrequest setNetworkServiceType:NSURLNetworkServiceTypeVoIP];
```

According to `iOS` documentation, it should be possible :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/iphoneappprogrammingguide.pdf   (page 124)

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to set "Required background modes" to "App provides Voice over IP services" in your app plist.